# event handler functions on mat radio

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, radio-button

I have a little confusion on function call on radio buttons

I'm calling change function on mat radio

1st way is i call only a single change function on mat-radio-group

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="product_type" (change)="onProduct($event,i)">
    <mat-radio-button value="Plant">Plant and Related
    </mat-radio-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <mat-radio-button value="Drugs">
        Drugs and Related</mat-radio-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <mat-radio-button value="Others">Others
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

2nd way is i call my change function on seperate radio button

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="product_type">
    <mat-radio-button value="Plant" (change)="onPlant($event,i)">Plant and Related
    </mat-radio-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <mat-radio-button value="Drugs" (change)="onDrugs($event,i)">
        Drugs and Related</mat-radio-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <mat-radio-button value="Others" (change)="onOthers($event,i)">Others
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

For me both the way should act same if my logic to handle event is same but it doesn't.
Is there any difference between the 1st and 2nd way???????

Answer (score 0):

There is diff in calling the both type you described ,
You should call the change event always inside the
mat-radio-group so that any change that occurred inside the radio button can be detected but if you call it inside the mat-radio-button it won’t work

Comment: For me its working inside mat-radio-button. I treid both the way but my problem got solved by the later. So i had this doubt that is there any difference between them.